# Mac Lane-like condition for intrinsically linked graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors, planar-graphs, knot-link

If any embedding of your graph in 3-space has two cycles that are linked, then your graph is intrinsically linked (such as the Petersen graph). These graphs generalise non-planar graphs since for example any flat projection of these graphs will also be non-planar.

Non-planar graphs can also be characterised by [Mac Lane's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion): there is a cycle basis with a cycle sharing an edge with more than 2 cycles — i.e. the graph has a non-trivial cycle involving a non-planar edge. This is informative since it gives a more constructive explanation of non-planarity, rather than just a forbidden minors characterisation.

I would like to understand better the way that linked graphs generalise non-planar graphs. Is there a condition analogous to Mac Lane's condition that characterises linked graphs?

Comment: Doesn't Mac Lane's condition work the other way? I.e., a graph is non-planar if and only if *all of its cycles bases* have an edge contained in more than 2 cycles

Comment: Graphs are linklessly embeddable if and only if their $\mu$-invariant of Colin de Verdi\`ere is at most $4$. See the pertaining Wikipedia page.

Comment: Geometric conditions and reformulations were given by H. van der Holst (see the Wikipedia on $\mu$  for exact refences) if I am not mistaken, The $\mu$-invariant has a combinatorial description (found by L. Laszlo and Schrijver) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks @RolandBacher yes I think the invariant introduced in Holst09 (related to the $\mu$-invariant) is closest to what I'm looking for - it seems to generalise the Hanani–Tutte rather Mac Lane characterisation of planarity.